Continuity of a map between $\ell_1\times \ell_1$ and $\mathbf R$
Let $f\colon \ell_1\to \mathbf R$ be defined by $f((a_n)) = \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{g(na_n)}{n}$, where $g\colon\mathbf R\to \mathbf R$ is defined by $g(x) = \mathrm{ln}(1+x^2)$.
I am trying to show that the map (derivative) $D\colon \ell_1\times \ell_1\to \mathbf R$ is $C^0$.
If we define $Df((a_n),(b_n)) = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f\big((a_n)+t(b_n)\big) - f\big((a_n)\big)}{t}$
is continuous. It is easy to see that $Df((a_n),(b_n))=\sum_{n\geq 1}b_ng'(a_n)$ just by using the limit. Moreover, by the mean value theorem, $|g'(x)|\leq 1$. Hence it follows easily that $|Df((a_n),(b_n))|\leq \|(b_n)\|_1$. Now $Df$ is linear in $(b_n)$ hence this boundedness implies continuity in the second argument. But I am stuck at making a concrete argument as to why it is jointly continuous.

EDIT: the question can be rephrased as follows:
Let $g\colon \mathbf R\to \mathbf R$ is continuous (not necessarily linear) such that $|g(x)|\leq 1$ for all $x\in\mathbf R$. Is $F\colon \ell_1^2\to \mathbf R$, $F(a,b)= \sum_{n\geq 1} a_n g(b_n)$ continuous?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Yes, your $F$ is continuous. To see this, let $\varepsilon >0$ and $a^0,b^0\in\ell^1$. Then $b^0$ is bounded, hence $|b_n^0|\le K$ for all $n$. Next, $g$ is uniformly continuous on the compact set $I := [-K-1,K+1]$. Hence, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $x,y\in I$, $|x-y| < \delta$ implies $|g(x)-g(y)| < \varepsilon/(2\|a^0\|_1)$. We may assume that $\delta < 1$ and $\delta < \varepsilon/2$.
Let $a,b\in\ell^1$ such that $\|a-a^0\|_1,\|b-b^0\|_1 < \delta$. Since $\delta < 1$ and $|b_n - b_n^0| < \delta$, we have $|b_n|\le K+1$, i.e., $b_n\in I$ for all $n$. Thus, $|g(b_n) - g(b_n^0)| < \varepsilon/(2\|a^0\|_1)$ for all $n$. Now, we may estimate
\begin{align}
|F(a,b)-F(a^0,b^0)|
&= \bigg|\sum_n [a_ng(b_n) - a_n^0g(b_n^0)]\bigg|\\
&\le \sum_n |a_ng(b_n) - a_n^0g(b_n)| + \sum_n |a_n^0g(b_n) - a_n^0g(b_n^0)|\\
&= \sum_n |a_n - a_n^0||g(b_n)| + \sum_n |a_n^0||g(b_n) - g(b_n^0)|\\
&\le \sum_n |a_n - a_n^0| + \frac{\varepsilon}{2\|a^0\|_1}\sum_n |a_n^0|\\
&= \|a_n-a_n^0\|_1 + \frac\varepsilon 2 < \varepsilon.
\end{align}
